# Is $\alpha \mapsto \beth_\alpha$ a Veblen function? Is $\alpha \mapsto \aleph_\alpha$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I learned what a [Veblen function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_function) is a few days ago. It is a function from ordinals to ordinals that's strictly monotonic increasing and continuous.

The Wikipedia article is a little bit difficult to understand, mostly because I don't really know what the relevant notion of continuity is when discussing ordinal-valued functions.

So, are $\alpha \mapsto \beth_\alpha$ and $\alpha \mapsto \aleph_\alpha$ Veblen functions? They are monotonic increasing in the sense that don't reverse $\le$ and are injective, but I don't know whether they're continuous or not. My gut says that these functions *spread out* the domain too much and their images, intuitively, have tons of gaps, but I don't know how this relates to the relevant notion of continuity.

Comment: A function from ordinals to ordinals that is increasing and continuous is more commonly known as a [normal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_function). They provide a particularly nice characterization of club subsets of ordinals: clubs are exactly ranges of normal functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, a terminological quibble. I've never heard the term "Veblen function" used to refer to *any* strictly increasing continuous function. Rather, in my experience it's reserved for those which arise via "climbing up" some system of ordinal notations.

That said, your question still makes perfect sense: you're asking whether the $\aleph$- and $\beth$-functions are continuous. The answer is **yes**, and this is directly from how they're defined at limit ordinals: both $\aleph_-$ and $\beth_-$ are examples of functions $F$ satisfying the **limit rule** $$F(\lambda)=\sup\{F(\alpha):\alpha<\lambda\}$$ for each limit ordinal $\lambda$. Any nondecreasing function satisfying this limit rule is continuous *(it's a good exercise to show that I do need "nondecreasing" here - if I want to generalize to all functions I need a more complicated limit rule)*.

Keep in mind that in the ordinals, every successor ordinal is isolated, so interesting topological behavior is **really focused on limit ordinals**. The fact that e.g. $\beth_\alpha$ is often much bigger than $\alpha$ doesn't matter - all that matters is that $\beth_\lambda$ doesn't "jump past" the sequence $(\beth_\alpha)_{\alpha<\lambda}$ when $\lambda$ is a limit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a follow up question if that's okay. I'm assuming that we can assess the continuity of an arbitrary ordinal-valued function by using some class-sized topology associated with the ordinals ... which (class-)topology is it? Does it even make sense to ask that?

Comment: @GregoryNisbet It's the (class-sized version of the) [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology).

Comment: @GregoryNisbet. Out of many equivalent definitions of continuity, the one that is usually best suited for functions on ordinals is that $f:B\to C$ is continuous iff $f(x)\in Cl_C(f[A]])$ whenever $A\subset B$ and $x\in Cl_B(A).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, thank you. What does $\mathrm{Cl}_X(Y)$ mean? I think $f[...]$ means preimage.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet No, $f[X]$ is *image*: it's $\{f(x): x\in X\}$. Preimage would be $f^{-1}[X]$. Meanwhile, "$Cl_X(Y)$" is just "the closure of $Y$ in the (sub)space $X$" - which is $Y$ together with the limit points (in the sense of $X$) of $Y$. In the case where $B$ is the class of all ordinals, this boils down to "$f(x)$ is either in $f[A]$ or is a limit of ordinals in $f[A]$ whenever $x$ is in $A$ or a limit of ordinals in $A$."